# How to make a chrome extension work immediately on a new page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to get my extension to act immediately upon a new page instead of when I click a button. For example, this code works in terms of changing the words on the page, but only once I click a button from my default popup. How can I make it to where it acts immediately once a user changes pages. I tried making a new .js file but it won't do anything.

```
function change(){
  const text = document.querySelectorAll("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, p, li, td, caption, span, a")
for(let i=0;i<text.length;i++){
  if(text[i].innerHTML.includes("The")){
    text[i].innerHTML = text[i].innerHTML.replace("The","A")
  }
  
}
}
change();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use content_scripts.

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "hoge",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "matches.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

matches.js

```
function change(){
  const text = document.querySelectorAll("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, p, li, td, caption, span, a")
for(let i=0;i<text.length;i++){
  if(text[i].innerHTML.includes("The")){
    text[i].innerHTML = text[i].innerHTML.replace("The","A")
  }
  
}
}
change();
```